# Prove/Disprove: If $A\cap B=\emptyset $ and $Span(A)\cap Span(B)\neq \{0\}$ so $A \cup B$ is linear dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove/Disprove:
>
> Let $V$ be a vector space and $A,B\subseteq V$ subsets.
>
> If $A\cap B=\emptyset $ and $Span(A)\cap Span(B)\neq \{0\}$ so $A \cup B$ is linear dependent

I am a bit rusty with the notion of union of vector spaces, if we take $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,0)$ so the union is $\{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$?

So it seems it is a proof, but how should I approach this?

Comment: I think you meant "$Span(A)\cap Span(B)\neq 0$" (i.e. there's a non-zero common vector in those spans) instead of "$\neq\emptyset$" since the latter condition is always true: spans always have $0$ as a common element. So what would be the point of such condition?

Comment: Correct, edtied

Answer (score 1):

It is false, as your example almost shows. Take $V = \mathbb R^2$ and $A = \{(0, 1)\}$ and $B = \{(1, 0)\}$. The two sets are disjoint, and the intersection of their spans contains the zero vector, but their union is $\{(0, 1), (1, 0)\}$, which is linearly independent.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are not vector spaces or spans or subspaces. They are merely regular subsets.

Comment: Sorry, wanted to edit the comment, in general if $A=(1,0)$ and $B=(0,1)$ so $A\cup B=\{(1,0),(0,1),\{(1,0),(0,1)\}\}$?

Comment: Answering myself :) the above is not a union

Comment: @gbox Please read my comment to your question. The condition $Span(A)\cap Span(B)\neq\emptyset$ is pointless: that **always** holds, no matter what $A, B$ is.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the condition

$$Span(A)\cap Span(B)\neq\emptyset$$

is pointless since that holds for **all** $A,B$ because $0\in Span(X)$ no matter what $X$ is. With that in mind you take any vector space $V$, you take any linearly independent set $C$ and you take any two non-empty, disjoint subsets $A,B\subseteq C$. These will satisfy your conditions.

However the interesting condition would be

$$Span(A)\cap Span(B)\neq 0$$

i.e. $Span(A)$ and $Span(B)$ have a common, non-zero vector. In that case the statement is indeed true.

---

Let $v\in Span(A)\cap Span(B)$ be a non-zero vector. Then

$$v=\sum\lambda_i a_i$$
$$v=\sum\beta_j b_j$$

for some $\{a_i\}\subseteq A$ and $\{b_j\}\subseteq B$. Since $v$ is nonzero then there exists $i_0$ such that $\lambda_{i_0}\neq 0$. Then

$$\lambda_{i_0}a_{i_0} + \sum_{i\neq i_0}\lambda_i a_i=\sum\beta_j b_j$$

and so

$$\lambda_{i_0}a_{i_0} + \sum_{i\neq i_0}\lambda_i a_i-\sum\beta_j b_j=0$$

Since $A\cap B=\emptyset$ then it follows that $A\cup B$ is linearly 
dependent because $\lambda_{i_0}a_{i_0}$ term cannot disappear.